# In Eclipse (Aptana plugin), change annotation / highlighting for matching text when executing a find /search?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, annotations, aptana

When searching for text within Eclipse using the Find bar (Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604), the matching text within the file is highlighted in a faint color.

How can we change how matching text is highlighted?

We're using the Aptana Plugin.

We have searched all over, and none of the Annotation settings seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The color used for highlighting matching text is the same as the selection color, and if you are using Aptana editor, to change the selection color, you would go to **Preferences** > **Aptana Studio** > **Themes** and modify the color for **Selection** in the current theme.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Related question: if a cursor rests on a word for more than a few seconds, it highlights all instances of that word. Do you know how to change this behavior?

Comment: Also, I can't quite seem to change the background color of the text that is highlighted during the find process ... all we can do is change the selection color.

Comment: That functionality is called "Mark occurrences". You could turn it off by unchecking "Mark occurrences with background color" in Preferences > Aptana Studio > HTML/JSS/etc page.

Comment: And I don't think the text background color when selected could be changed via preferences.

Comment: Can we change "Mark occurrences" to occur on some other condition, or delay it a few more seconds?

Comment: Currently such options do not exist yet. I'd recommend to file feature request at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD on the conditions you would like to be able to set.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. As for the background highlighting, I still can't get the view uniform as you can see from the attached image (updated the question). How can I get both sides as black as the right side? The left side has a gray sheen. I looked through the Themes section per your recommendation, but can't tell which elements control the .HTML.ERB files (as opposed to .RB files).

Comment: We solved the background highlighting issue. Anything with script or style tags had a gray/dim white background color which impaired visibility. To set this to a black, update the "Embedded Source" elements from the Theme dialog.

Comment: Hi Crashalot, apologize for not getting back to you; forgot to log back on for a week. Good to hear you finally got the background issue resolved.

Comment: If this doesn't appear to be the right setting because the color you're seeing doesn't match the color of selected text, try it anyway. I found that the color it was showing in the preference window wasn't the one it was actually using, but after I changed it to a very similar color, it changed it to what it looked like it was in the first place.